# When is hashValue in swift computed?

Tags: swift, swift-hashable

Let's say I have a massive String, so hashing it is fairly expensive.

When does the hashValue gets computed? Every time I access it as `words.hashValue`, or every time the String gets modified? If it's on access, is it cached?

Comment: "If it's on access, is it cached?" Yes. There's a "witness table".

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue) on `hashValue` state, that requirement on `Hashable` is deprecated, you should be using `hash(into:)` instead, which should only be called when you are storing the `String` as a `Hashable`, by using it as a `Dictionary` key or in a `Set`.

For more info, see [SE-0206 Hashable enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md).

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers the question that was actually asked.

Comment: @matt OP shouldn't be using `hashValue` in the first place, so when it gets calculated is irrelevant. `hash(into:)` should be used instead. And I did answer when `hash(into:)` gets called.

Comment: But the question is not about what the OP should be doing. The `hashValue` does exist and it is perfectly reasonable to wonder about its cost.